# Journal name not showing up with custom citation style when BibTeX field type is "journal"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

I am currently trying (again) to implement a custom citation style which should end in a list of publications, and generally it works. My tex file is very simple:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[datamodel=reference_class_definitions,backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,giveninits=true,style=science]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{publication_data.bib}
\input{citation_style_definitions}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \fullcite{Author1981}.
\end{enumerate}
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

It uses the files `reference_class_definitions.dbx`, `citation_style_definitions.tex` (which somehow define the custom output style, see below for their contents) and `publication_data.bib` (containing bibliographic data of exactly one paper):

```
@Article{Author1981,
  author   = {Author, One and Author, Two},
  journal_name  = {Journal of Fancy Research},
  title    = {Some paper title},
  year     = {1981},
  number   = {6},
  pages    = {1247-1260},
  volume   = {20},
  doi   = {10.someRandomNumber},
  type     = {Journal Article},
}
```

The output is exactly what I want:

[image: Output with journal name]

However, I observe a strange behavior when I try to change the name of the field "journal_name" to "journal" in `publication_data.bib`. Of course I also change all instances of "journal_name" in `reference_class_definitions.dbx` and `citation_style_definitions.tex` to "journal", but the output does not show the journal name:

[image: Output without journal name]

I am having trouble to understand this behavior, so my question is: Why is the journal name not showing up when changing "journal_name" to "journal"? Any other name does work, for example "published_in" instead of "journal_name" is no problem at all. I would prefer "journal" however because to my understanding it is one of the fields recognized by the standard bibliography styles.

---

`reference_class_definitions.dbx` contains:

```
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{article}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  title,
  journal_name,
  volume,
  pages,
  ISSN,
  DOI,
  url,
  year,
  type
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  author
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[article]{
  author,
  title,
  journal_name,
  volume,
  pages,
  ISSN,
  DOI,
  url,
  year,
  type}
```

`citation_style_definitions.tex` contains:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{author}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibquote{\textit{#1}}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journal_name}{\textit{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textit{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{DOI}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{year}{\textbf{#1}\isdot}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \addcomma\setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \addcomma\setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{journal_name}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \addcomma\setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{volume}
  \addcomma\setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{pages}
  \addcomma\addspace%
  DOI:\setunit{\addspace}\printfield{DOI}
  \addperiod\setunit{\addspace}%
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`journal` is a bit of a tricky field. It isn't really part of the standard data model. Instead it is resolved as an alias for `journaltitle` via the default driver source map ([ll. 1339-1371 in `biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/24a94f8f608872e11d259d7c581fc90ea76542a5/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L1339-L1371)). In your example with `journal` the sourcemap gets executed and remaps `journal` to `journaltitle` and then your data model never gets to see any `journal`.

You can wipe out the default driver sourcemap with `\DeclareDriverSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{}` (or you can copy only the bits you like and drop the things you don't like from the definition linked above).

```
\begin{filecontents}{reference_class_definitions.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{article}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  title,
  journal,
  volume,
  pages,
  ISSN,
  DOI,
  url,
  year,
  type
}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{
  author
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[article]{
  author,
  title,
  journal,
  volume,
  pages,
  ISSN,
  DOI,
  url,
  year,
  type}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Author1981,
  author   = {Author, One and Author, Two},
  journal  = {Journal of Fancy Research},
  title    = {Some paper title},
  year     = {1981},
  number   = {6},
  pages    = {1247-1260},
  volume   = {20},
  doi      = {10.someRandomNumber},
  type     = {Journal Article},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[datamodel=reference_class_definitions,backend=biber,maxbibnames=99,giveninits=true,style=science]{biblatex}

\DeclareDriverSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{author}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibquote{\textit{#1}}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journal_name}{\textit{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textit{#1}\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{DOI}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{year}{\textbf{#1}\isdot}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \addcomma\setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \addcomma\setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{journal}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \addcomma\setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{volume}
  \addcomma\setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{pages}
  \addcomma\addspace%
  DOI:\setunit{\addspace}\printfield{DOI}
  \addperiod\setunit{\addspace}%
}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \fullcite{Author1981}.
\end{enumerate}
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

[image: 1. O. Author, T. Author, “Some paper title”, Journal of Fancy Research 1981, 20, 1247-1260, DOI: 10.someRandomNumber.]

At least in this example I don't really understand why you need the new data model at all. With the exception of `type` all fields you define (and the issue of `journal_name`/`journal` we just discussed) are already known for `@article` in the standard data model. The `type = {Journal Article},` is already pretty much implied by using `@article`, but if you need more fine-grained control there is `entrysubtype`.

Bare punctuation like `\addcomma` and friends outside of `\setunit` and friends are not encouraged in bibliography drivers or bibmacros since they bypass the punctuation buffer and can lead to undesirable (double)punctuation. Similarly naked text like "DOI:" is usually discouraged there and should instead be moved to `\DeclareFieldFormat` and friends.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Another workaround resulting from your answer is to replace "journal" by "journaltitle" in `reference_class_definitions.dbx` and `citation_style_definitions.tex`. Then the resulting output is fine with a "journal" field in the bib file. I will probably be very much confused by this in two years or so when I have a look at the files again...